# addthis's script fails to load in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, addthis

I've added addthis.com's code to my HTML page.
But Google Chrome shows a status failed for getting this url :

```
x Failed to load resource
GET http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51aee1dc1b323034
```

The addthis widget shows in FireFox on my PC but not on my colleague's where on loading that URL shows **Content Encoding Error**.

Im unable to find the root cause of this. Is it addthis's script or does it have something to do with my implementation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. Try using `https`. It solved the problem for me.

```
https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51aee1dc1b323034
```

Comment: to cover both http and https it should be enough to remove `http:` or `https:` this way: `//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51aee1dc1b323034`

Comment: I have this same problem.. tried with only // http://and https:// and no luck. works in firefox but not chrome.

Answer (score 5):

AdBlock and other extensions block "addthis"
http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/problems/26572-adblock-blocking-adthis-widget

Comment: rip, this link is 404 now, the forum has changed and that post seems to have been removed. I tried searching for addthis in that forum with no result

Answer (score 1):

I tried in every possible way for a day (http to https, CORS, etc). But failed. Then disable all the Extensions in Chrome. Eureka!!! It's Avast bloking the [addthis_widget.js](http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Avast Online Security extension installed in your browser just disable it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue:

GET https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

The console error states it was blocked by client (me): so I checked and found out I had adblockers enabled in my browser, thus: I then added the site to whitelist and voila: AddThis started working!

In addition:

//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51aee1dc1b323034

The above accounts for both Http and Https.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenWRT (and I imagine DD-WRT and others) on your router and using any of the adblock services/plugins, you need to add s7.addthis.com to the `Services > Adblock` whitelist.

The specific error is

> https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

You'll get similar errors for Google and Bing analytics and other similar services too.